# Checking non-virtual inheritance during compile time

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

I'm trying to determine during compile time if A is a non-virtual ancestor of B, without using any third party tools or 'is_base_of'. after quite a bit of search I learned a little about the SFINAE mechanism and this is the code I came up with:

```cpp
template <typename P>
struct helper : public P {

};
template <typename CHILD, typename PARENT>
struct appendix : public CHILD, public helper<PARENT> {
    static constexpr appendix<CHILD,PARENT>* getClassType();

    static bool val(PARENT* p);
    static int val(...);

    enum {
        value = sizeof(val(getClassType())) == sizeof(bool)
    };
};
```

My thought was that if PARENT is an ancestor of CHILD the ambiguous conversion error will cause the compiler to use the seconds definition of 'val', but instead it just gives compile error.

1) Can someone suggest a working solution?

2) Why doesn't the code snippet above works? I'm no expert at all in anything related to templates (it looks amazingly hard to be an expert on this subject) but I don't see why it doesn't work

Edit: usage of static_cast is also forbidden

Comment: What is the error you're getting? The code compiles on gcc and clang but didn't give the right answer.

Comment: Define "non-virtual inheritance". I'm sure that an SFINAE-based template can be crafted to test if CHILD inherits from PARENT. However, I don't think it's possible to discriminate between virtual and non-virtual inheritance.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You might be able to SFINAE on the well-formedness of a `static_cast` from `B*` to `D*` (which is ill-formed for virtual inheritance)

Comment: @T.C. I should have mentioned that static_cast is also forbidden. Its part of an exercise to implement custom static_cast

Comment: @0x499602D2 ambiguous base class error

Comment: In that case, for this kind of a situation, where you're told you can't do this, and you can't do that, etc..., I'm sure your instructor has already lectured on exactly what kind of an approach he or she expects you to use in order to complete your assignment. I suggest that you consult your class notes and determine exactly how you are expected to implement something like this. Nobody here, unfortunately, has a mind ray-beam machine to pull out of your instructor's head exactly what you're supposed to do.